# With hindsight and in hindsight

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain to me the difference between the use of "in hindsight" and "with hindsight"?

For example, with (the benefit/wisdom of) hindsight, I should have taken the job. In hindsight, it would have been better to wait.

(Hindsight definition: the ability to understand an event or situation only after it has happened)

Comment: *with* -> *Indicating the instrument used to perform an action:* (Oxford)

Answer (score 2):

Adding some extra words can help to bring out what nuances exist (if any):

> - With [the benefit of] hindsight, I should have taken the job.
> - In [the light of] hindsight, it would have been better to wait.

We can see that, when speaking of hindsight, *with* indicates possession, whereas *in* indicates location (viewpoint).

Comment: Mick, what difference would it make if the halves of those sentences were swapped, please?